# Is there some "Feature Graphic" generator for Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm looking for some "Feature Graphic" online generator. Feature Graphic is the big image displayed in the web-based Android Market.

It could be something simple and it could look like one for this app: https://market.android.com/details?id=menion.android.locus

I would input screenshots, title and some slogan and it would generate nice feature graphic. I think many Android developers would appreciate such service.

Comment: that would be great if such a thing existed. maybe it could take a collection of screenshots and turn them into something like widgetlocker's feature graphic. https://market.android.com/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker

Comment: This question with his answer are really useful for those who are not a designer and can't effort / don't want to pay one.

Comment: You can generate android feature graphics from this page [link](http://uncaughterror.com/tools/android-feature-graphic-generator/)

Comment: https://hotpot.ai/design/google-play-feature-graphic?id=33 use this @David

Answer (score 91, accepted):

As of 31st Aug 2014 feature graphic is mandatory and handily there's a generator Created by Litrik De Roy [here](http://www.norio.be/android-feature-graphic-generator/).

> The Android Feature Graphic Generator allows you to easily create a
>   simple yet attractive feature graphic for your Android application. It
>   will generate a PNG image file according to Google's guidelines.
>   Afterwards you can upload the image to the Google Play Developer
>   Console to spice up the listing of your Android app.

Answer (score 15):

Try [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org)

Or [PhotoShop](http://www.photoshop.com/products/photoshop)

Both require some degree of experience. But if you're software developer, you need basic graphics manipulation skills anyway.

Comment: Yeah I use Gimp also, but it could look better - some nice effects on the screenshots, text in nice font etc. I don't want to spend too much time with experimenting about this with GIMP. Some online tool like Android Asset Studio would be great.

Comment: Ye, i'd go for Gimp too. Free and has similar features to Photoshop. Put some time into learning the ropes and you'll be able to make something quite good.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it would be a nice service but be careful screenshot in feature graphics are not recommended. See the post on the Android Developer Blog about Feature Graphics http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-market-featured-image.html

I built the feature graphic for my app https://market.android.com/details?id=com.grunewaldsrobots.saskbus with Inkscape http://inkscape.org/ using some of the assets generated from the Asset Studio.

Also a quote from the [Android Market Help](https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?answer=1078870)

> Feature Graphic (Optional):
>
> - Use: The featured section in Android Market. Will be downsized to mini or micro.
> - Specs: 1024w x 500h, 24 bit PNG or JPEG (no alpha) with no transparency
> - Tips:
>
>   - Use a safe frame of 924x400 (50 pixel of safe padding on each side). All the important content of the graphic should be within this safe frame. Pixels outside of this safe frame may be cropped for stylistic purposes.
>   - If incorporating text, use large font sizes, and keep the graphic simple, as this graphic may be scaled down from its original size.
>   - This graphic may be displayed alone without the app icon.

Comment: Good point, we should not add screenshots there because it will be scaled down on mobile version on Market. Some service which would take logo, app name, slogan and added some nice effects would be nice.